# I want to insert multiple Account Records with visualforce but i am getting error(Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.)

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, database.insert

//My visualforce page code

```
<apex:page controller="AddMulAccountContr" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{! listaccount}" var="acc">
           
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.Name}" />
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                       <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.Type}" />
                </apex:column>   
               <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">    
                          <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.Industry}" />
               </apex:column> 
           
        
        </apex:pageblockTable>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                 <apex:commandbutton value="add multiple accounts" action="{!addmulrec}" />
                  <apex:commandbutton value="save account" action="{ !saveAccount}" />
        
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
        
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

//My controller class

```
public class AddMulAccountContr {
    public  List<Account> listaccount{get;set;}
    Account a = new Account();
    public AddMulAccountContr(){
        
       listaccount = new List<Account>();
       listAccount.add(a) ;
        
    }
    public void addmulrec(){
        Account acc = new Account();
        listaccount.add(acc);
    }
    public PageReference saveAccount() {
              for(Integer i=0; i<listAccount.size(); i++)
              {
                 insert listaccount;
               }
                     return Page.pagerefdemo2;    
                       }
    

}
```

//my pagerefdEMO2
<apex:page >

```
        <h1>
          RECORDS INSERTED
        </h1>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: typo: `action="{ !saveAccount}"` should be `action="{!saveAccount}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run this snippet in dev org and I see that you are trying to loop in action attributes over the list of accounts while saving them.

To fix this, you can just simply ignore the loop while performing save action in your saveAccount() method in the AddMulAccountContr controller as below:

```
public class AddMulAccountContr {
public  List<Account> listaccount{get;set;}
Account a = new Account();
public AddMulAccountContr(){
    
    listaccount = new List<Account>();
    listAccount.add(a) ;
    
}
public void addmulrec(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    listaccount.add(acc);
}
public PageReference saveAccount() {
    
    insert listaccount;
    
    return Page.pagerefdemo2; 
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It works for me

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is you have a typo here (space between `{` and `!` ):

```
action="{ !saveAccount}"
```

should be

```
action="{!saveAccount}"
```

This won't be detected by the VF compiler but appears as a runtime error when you click the button